# How do i edit existing info with winforms

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, streamreader, streamwriter

I am developing a calendar/appointment application and when i double click on the appointment while the application is running i want it to open the form with the information typed before and edit all.(with streamwriter and streamreader)!

```
private void editToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // Raised by selecting Edit on the content menu

     // TODO - You need to complete this method.
     // _SelectedAppointment is set to the instance of the appointment to be edited

}
```

I have a main form with a month calendar

```
private void monthCalendar_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
        {
            labelDisplayedDate.Text=monthCalendar.SelectionRange.Start.ToLongDateString();
            GetAppointmentsOnSelectedDate(monthCalendar.SelectionRange.Start);
            // Force repaint of daily view panel
            panelDailyView.Invalidate();
        }
```

a panel

```
private void panelDailyView_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            int paintWidth = panelDailyView.ClientRectangle.Size.Width - vScrollBar.Width;
            int paintHeight = panelDailyView.ClientRectangle.Size.Height;
            int displayedRowCount = paintHeight / PanelRowHeight;
            int panelTopRow;
            int nextRow;
            int apptStartRow;
            int apptLength;
            string dispTime; 

            Font font = new Font("Arial", 10);
            Brush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.DarkBlue);
            Brush appointmentBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.LightBlue);

            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            // Fill the background of the panel
            g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Linen), 0, 0, paintWidth, paintHeight);
            panelTopRow = vScrollBar.Value;
            if (_SelectedRow >= panelTopRow &&
                _SelectedRow <= panelTopRow + displayedRowCount)
            {
                // If the selected time is displayed, mark it
                g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.DarkKhaki), 
                                0, 
                                (_SelectedRow - panelTopRow) * PanelRowHeight,
                                paintWidth,
                                PanelRowHeight);
            }
            // Display the times at the start of the rows and
            // the lines separating the rows
            nextRow = panelTopRow;
            for (int i = 0; i <= displayedRowCount; i++)
            {
                dispTime = (nextRow / 2).ToString("0#") + (nextRow % 2 == 0 ? ":00" : ":30");
                nextRow++;
                g.DrawString(dispTime, font, drawBrush, 2, (i * PanelRowHeight + 4));
                g.DrawLine(Pens.DarkBlue, 0, i * PanelRowHeight, paintWidth, i * PanelRowHeight);
            }
            // Now fill in the appointments
            foreach (IAppointment appointment in _TodaysAppointments)
            {
                apptStartRow = Utility.ConvertTimeToRow(appointment.Start);
                apptLength = Utility.ConvertLengthToRows(appointment.Length);
                // See if the appointment is inside the part of the day displayed on the panel
                if (((apptStartRow >= panelTopRow) && 
                     (apptStartRow <= panelTopRow + displayedRowCount)) ||
                    (apptStartRow + apptLength > panelTopRow))
                {
                    // Calculate the area of the panel occupied by
                    // the appointment
                    if (apptStartRow < panelTopRow)
                    {
                        apptLength = apptLength - (panelTopRow - apptStartRow);
                        apptStartRow = panelTopRow;
                    }
                    int apptDispStart = (apptStartRow - panelTopRow) * PanelRowHeight;
                    int apptDispLength = apptLength * PanelRowHeight;
                    if (apptDispStart + apptDispLength > paintHeight)  
                    {
                        apptDispLength = paintHeight - apptDispStart;
                    }
                    Rectangle apptRectangle = new Rectangle(ApptOffset,
                                                            apptDispStart,
                                                            paintWidth - (ApptOffset * 2),
                                                            apptDispLength);
                    // Draw the block of light blue
                    g.FillRectangle(appointmentBrush,
                                    apptRectangle);
                    // Draw the black line around it
                    g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, apptRectangle);
                    if (Utility.ConvertTimeToRow(appointment.Start) >= panelTopRow)
                    {
                        // If the top line of the appointment is displayed,
                        // write out the subject and location.  Temporarily
                        // reduce the clip area for the graphics object to ensure
                        // that the text does not extend beyond the rectangle
                        Region oldClip = g.Clip;
                        g.Clip = new Region(apptRectangle);
                        g.DrawString(appointment.DisplayableDescription,
                                     font,
                                     drawBrush,
                                     ApptOffset + 6,
                                     apptDispStart + 4);
                        g.Clip = oldClip;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

and 2 buttons

```
private void buttonNewAppt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NewAppointment();
            NewAppointment form2 = new NewAppointment();
            form2.ShowDialog();
        }

private void buttonNewReccuringAppt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NewRecurringAppointment();
            RecurringAppointmentForm form3 = new RecurringAppointmentForm();
            form3.ShowDialog();
        }
```

each button loads a form, the appointment form and the recurring appointment form. what i want is when an appointment is showing on the panel and double click it, to edit it. if it is an appointment the appointment form should load, or if it is recurring appointment, the recurring appointment form should load and edit it.

Comment: And what is the problem/question?

Answer (score 1):

Handle the `MouseDoubleClick`-event, select the appointment/recurring appointment by coords and open the corresponding editor.

```
private void panelDailyView_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    IAppointment appointment = CheckForAppointment(e.X, e.Y); 
    if (appointment != null) 
    { 
        if (appointment.IsRecurring)
        {
            using(RecurringAppointmentForm form3 = new RecurringAppointmentForm(appointment))
                form3.ShowDialog();
        }
        else
        {
            using(RecurringAppointmentForm form3 = new RecurringAppointmentForm(appointment))
                form3.ShowDialog();
        }
    } 
}

private void CheckForAppointment(int x, int y);
```

For this part, you need to remember, where you placed the appointments. For example if you have a list where for each appointment is stored, on which x,y-coord it is and which size it has, you can iterate over that list in order to find a rectangle, which contains your click-coords.

Comment: this is my problem, i don't know how to do this.

Comment: The event-handling, the selection of the item or opening the corresponding editor?

Comment: Any of those. it passed more than a year of practicing and i forgot many things.

Comment: private void panelDailyView_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            IAppointment appointment = CheckForAppointment(e);
            if (appointment != null)
            {
                // TODO - 
            }
        }

this is my MouseDoubleClick

Comment: public RecurringAppointmentForm(IAppointment appointment)
        {
            this.appointment = appointment;
        }
after i do what you said i try to implement this but i'm stacked here